# Add sample point and add the results in the input layer

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, qgis-modeler

I'm a rookie of GIS programming and this is my question.

Basically, I need to sample the raster value for certain points and add the result to a new column in the attribute table of the point layer.
Then simply do not create a new layer for the results but add the result as a new column of the starting layer.

I programmed this model but I have no result in the attribute table of the point layer, where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: `Sample raster value` algorithm is designed to create a new layer, so you should define an output: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#sample-raster-values This algorithm is not compatible with in-place modifications, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-processing-in-place-layer-modifier

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the GRASS [module](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/v.what.rast.html) `v.what.rast` (appears in the Processing Toolbox). Here, you choose an existing column in your points attribute table, and the module extracts raster values at the point locations, and updates that column with the values.
Take care that both vector and raster are in the same coordinate reference system.